Jest tests encounters unexpected token - ES6 module
I recently updated a package in my repo and when I then run the tests I get 28/339 tests failing due to Jest encountering an unexpected token.
The error I get is this:
Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/DMCFADDE/altorepos/<REPO_NAME>/node_modules/iframe-coordinator/dist/index.js:3815
    export { Client, FrameRouterElement, registerCustomElements };
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

    > 1 | import { Client } from 'iframe-coordinator';
        | ^

I have looked at every single StackOverflow forum on this issue as others have gotten it, no luck in getting them to work with me either.
I have tried adding it to the transformIgnorePatterns in my package.json:
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "node_modules/(?!<PACKAGE_NAME>/).+\\.js$"
]

I have tried using the babel-jest preset. I have also tried using the ts-jest preset.

you might check node version and your settings for ES version in tsconfig.json.  "target": ... , "module": ... and or "lib":  should have ECMA versions specified.
